# 'in order to meet her' VS. 'to meet her' any difference could be?

Tags: meaning

> I went there in order to meet her VS. I went there to meet her.

Could be any difference?

I think my question should be more specific.

'in' is a preposition and 'order' is a noun. I know 'in' but 'order' has many meanings.

What does the 'order' here mean as a noun?

I see some people explain on this site 'in the intention to to do something', then the 'order's meaning is 'intention' but I couldn't find the meaning in any ordinary dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/order):

> in order to
>
> : to make it possible for something to happen

And according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/order#etymonline_v_44543):

> In order "in proper sequence or arrangement" is from c. 1400; out of
> order "not in proper sequence or orderly arrangement" is from 1540s;
> since 20c. principally mechanical, but not originally so ("and so
> home, and there find my wife mightily out of order, and reproaching of
> Mrs. Pierce and Knipp as wenches, and I know not what," - Pepys,
> diary, Aug. 6, 1666).
>
> **Phrase in order to "for the purpose of" (1650s) preserves etymological
> notion of "sequence.**

It means ***sequence***.

### Your first question

> I went there in order to meet her VS. I went there to meet her.

Could be any difference?

Yes.  *In order to* is somewhat more formal.

Consider:

> Little Johnny, why did you go to the store?
>
> --I went to buy some candy.
>
> --I went in order to buy some candy.     (unlikely register)